# Is my fermentation on the right track?

Tags: yeast, all-grain, stuck-fermentation, high-gravity, repitch

I upgraded my equipment and estimated my new efficiency a bit too low, so the imperial IPA that I brewed on 11/30 ended up having an O.G. of 1.10 (supposed to be 1.09). I made a two step starter with White Labs California Ale (WLP001). The first step was 2L, and the second was a bit smaller at 1.2L since the first step went overboard a bit out of the erlenmeyer flask. I oxygenated with pure O2 for a minute and a few seconds before pitching. There was a little bit of bubbling the first 18 hours, but not much action until after 24 hours. It was really active for a week, and is now slowing down. There's still a 3/4" krausen, and I took a reading of 1.033 today (12/12). I'm looking to get to at least 1.02 (hopefully). The original recipe was supposed to finish around 1.01. I also should mention that I've been rousing the carboy occasionally. Not that it matters, but here's a bubble every 10 - 15 seconds in the air lock, 6.5 gallon carboy.

Should I pitch more yeast, or wait it out? I don't like leaving it on the trub for more than 3 weeks, but I don't want to rack to secondary until it's close to what I want. I was thinking to make a new starter and rack to secondary with the new starter. Any thoughts? I have never brewed a batch higher than 1.08, so this is new for me.

Comment: I'd give it at least a few days and a few more hydrometer readings before declaring a stuck fermentation.

Comment: Another indicator could be to check the temperature of the liquid when doing your reading. If it is equal to its surroundings it is usually a good sign that no fermentation is taking place.

Comment: @Sander - It's close to 2 degrees warmer (70) than the room (68). I started at 63 and slowly brought it up to 70.

Comment: It's too soon to worry, but for anyone to give you useful advice we need to know the recipe and your techniques, like mash temp.  Did you use sugar as is usually advised for IIPA?  If not, the beer could likely have fermented as much as it's going to.

Comment: @DennyConn - It should hopefully dry out more as my mash was held at 145 for 75 minutes, and there's a pound of dextrose in the mix (5 gallon batch). I'm just kinda looking for some recommendations in the hopes that someone has experience with this yeast and that gravity in terms of the time it takes to ferment. I guess I'll keep rousing it and take a reading every few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

001 is a pretty attenuative yeast.  You're simply impatient.  In a beer of that OG, I wouldn't even begin to worry until it had been over 3 weeks.  Leave it alone for another week or so and see where it is then.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear. I'm used to a quick fermentation with that mash temp and schedule, but I have more experience with WLP002. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I took a reading of 1.027 on 12/22 (1.033 on 12/12). A few days after stirring up the trub with a sanitized racking cane, there seemed to be a little more activity, but I'll only know after my next reading. Do you think I can get away with leaving it in the primary for over 3 weeks? Any risk of autolysis? I was going to start dry-hopping in the secondary, but would it hurt to add directly to the primary? I don't think I'll be washing this yeast.

Comment: You could leave it in primary for over a month and not have to worry about autolysis.